# How to use history.goBack for closing popup and how to close popup after opening it via direct link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, popup, router

I'm using react-router for opening popups in new URL address. It looks  something like this:

```
<Route path="/some-url/popup" children={({ match }) => (
  <Dialog onClose={history.goBack} open={Boolean(match)}>
    <PopupContent />
  </Dialog>
)} />
```

As you can see I want to clear browser history from opening and closing popups by history.goBack. But there is one case when a user opens a website by the direct link to this popup and then a user is not able to close popup for continuing using the website, as the previous route is not from our website. And as a result, the user is redirected from our site to the previous route after pressing the close popup button, but we want the user to stay on our website.

I created a small demo for you for a better understanding https://sin9k.com/popups-routes/posts

You can open this website, click for example on the button "Sign Up", then close the popup and you will see that you still on the website. But if you copy the link of the popup and paste it into a new tab in a browser you will leave the website back to the empty tab after closing popup.

Does anyone know a workaround for this case?

**UPDATED**

After some research i've created some video answer on the question with demo and GitHub.

EN: https://youtu.be/tl5_k6YBRKg

RU: https://youtu.be/fqYk-b1lhyI

demo: https://sin9k.com/close-popup

GitHub:   https://github.com/Sin9k/react-router-dom-tricks